# Read a list of partitions into dataframe with partition as column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a folder of NDJSON files in this structure:

```
s3://my_bucket/my_prefix/date=2023-05-01/
...                     /date=2023-05-02/
...                     /date=2023-05-03/
...                     ...
...                     /date=2023-09-01/
```

In each other partition, there are NDJSON files. I want to read a selected list of partitions into a PySpark dataframe, in Databricks Notebook, like this:

```
df = spark.read.text(path_list)
```

where `path_list` is a list of full paths as above.

However, I want to include a column `date` in this dataframe.

If I read the entire bucket, like this:

```
df = spark.read.text("s3://my_bucket")
```

I will have a column of `date` added to the dataframe.

How do I achieve this column by reading just a select `path_list`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's recreate your scenario with some really simple data:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("myVal1", "2023-05-01"),
        ("myVal2", "2023-05-02"),
        ("myVal3", "2023-05-03"),
        ("myVal4", "2023-09-01"),
    ],
    ["someVal", "date"],
)

df.write.partitionBy("date").json("myJson")
```

This creates a partitioned json file with the following structure:

```
myJson/
├── _SUCCESS
├── date=2023-05-01
│   └── part-00003-6d390070-5838-451a-9b26-b49500615a64.c000.json
├── date=2023-05-02
│   └── part-00007-6d390070-5838-451a-9b26-b49500615a64.c000.json
├── date=2023-05-03
│   └── part-00011-6d390070-5838-451a-9b26-b49500615a64.c000.json
└── date=2023-09-01
    └── part-00015-6d390070-5838-451a-9b26-b49500615a64.c000.json
```

Now, if you read want to read a selection of dates you can do this in 2 ways:

```py
df2 = spark.read.json(["./myJson/date=2023-05-01", "./myJson/date=2023-05-03"])
>>> df2.show()
+-------+
|someVal|
+-------+
| myVal1|
| myVal3|
+-------+

df3 = spark.read.json("./myJson").filter((F.col("date") == "2023-05-01") | (F.col("date") == "2023-05-03"))
>>> df3.show()
+-------+----------+
|someVal|      date|
+-------+----------+
| myVal3|2023-05-03|
| myVal1|2023-05-01|
+-------+----------+
```

So reading in the "full" data but filtering on the `date` column will get you there. And don't worry about performance, Spark is not really going to read in those other directories: thanks to the fact that your data is partitioned it can push that filter predicate down.

Comment: How about using the same command,  `df2 = spark.read.json(["./myJson/date=2023-05-01", "./myJson/date=2023-05-03"])` and then add a columns by `.withColumn("source_file_name", input_file_name())` and then substring the date part alone from it. This way they can use the first approach you suggested and read only the list of partitions needed and we get the column name as well ?

Comment: That is also possible, but it adds an extra step in your query plan (a `Project` step), so it will be less performant.